# How would I extract keywords from a product title?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape Newegg for pc parts. I got it to scrape parts, but I would like to know how I can shorten the name.

Example:

g.skill tridentz rgb series 16gb (2 x 8GB) 288-pin ddr4 sdram ddr4 3200 (pc4 25600) intel xmp 2.0 desktop memory model f4-3200c16d-16gtzr -> g.skill tridentz rgb series 16GB (2 x 8GB)

The problem I discovered is that the names always change and are not the same length. For example, the g.skill trident has a longer name than Kingston valueram 16GB (1 x 16GB).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

sites = 3
maxPages = [5,14,30]
scrapeInfo = [[],[],[]]
components = [[],[],[]]
brandOfRam = [] #
for mPage, site in zip(maxPages, range(sites)):
    for itter in range(1, mPage):
        scrapingInfoSite = [link1,link2]
        Products = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(scrapingInfoSite[site]).content, "html.parser")
        linksToProducts = Products.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
        scrapeInfo[site].append(linksToProducts)
        

for v,sector in enumerate(scrapeInfo):
    for page in sector:
        for link in page:
            Cpuname = " ".join(((str(link.text).lower()).split(" ")))
            try:
                components[v].index(Cpuname)
            except:
                components[v].append(Cpuname)
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. I am using python, and am using beautifulsoup4 for web scraping.

Comment: Try to find a rule to describe which part of the name should be kept as a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have been trying to find a rule, the issue is I just can't seem to find one.

Comment: Can you describe a rule in plain English?

Comment: A a statement that tells you what is or is not allowed in a situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really used to web scraping, so please be tolerant if I say something stupid.

You can already have the full length name for instance

```
g.skill tridentz rgb series 16gb (2 x 8GB) 288-pin ddr4 sdram ddr4 3200 (pc4 25600) intel xmp 2.0 desktop memory model f4-3200c16d-16gtzr
```

and you can split it, you already doing so afterwards in the code.

So your issue is that you want a shorter version of this string, with few tokens, but you can't just ask for like 6 tokens, cause other links may have less.

In that case, maybe you can decide to register a number of token equal to

```
max(6, len(str(link.text).lower()).split(" ")))
```

so you wont have issue with little links but still have a controlled amount of token on longer links

**Edit :** In your case, you can even set a constant nbrToken, then replace your Cpuname definition by

```
nbrToken = 6 #constant that you may choose

for v,sector in enumerate(scrapeInfo):
  for page in sector:
    for link in page:
        Cpuname = ((str(link.text).lower()).split(" "))
        Cpuname.reverse()
        while len(Cpuname) > nbrToken:
            Cpuname.pop(0)
        
        Cpuname.reverse()
        
        NewCName = " ".join(Cpuname)
```

That's *not* the best way to do it, and i didn't tried it with sample or something, but I hope it'll work and help you.

Here I just reverse the array composed of every token, pop them out till only *nbrToken* are left, then rereverse it. Then I use the join to have a string again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to improvise the URL, In most cases, the URL is much stable and meaningful (For SEO reason).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "Let's try to improvise the URL". Thank you

Comment: For example : https://www.newegg.com/global/th-en/g-skill-16gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820232476 

Is `g-skill-16gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram` in the URL is what are you looking for? 

Comment: Ok thanks, but the question is already solved